# DLNA Play-To on Script

Tags: scripts, dlna

Is there a way to push content to a DLNA capable TV via script on a loop.

We have a situation where TVs in a public place keep getting turned off by people walking by. Would like to be able to push content to TV every 15 minutes whether it is playing something or not.

Thoughts? Suggestions?
Thanks in advance.